# finding a equation parameter so that it has exactly 3 roots

Tags: real-analysis

let $f(x)=e^{\frac{1}{x}}$ find all m values so that $f(x)=mx^2$ has exactly 3 real roots

I have seen those kind of exercices often, can someone explain me what is the method of solving those?

Answer (score 0):

You want all $m$ such that $g(x) = f(x)/x^2 = \exp(1/x)/x^2$ takes the value $m$ exactly three times on $\mathbb R$.

Note that $g(x) > 0$ for all $x \ne 0$, with limits $0$ as $x \to -\infty$, $x \to 0-$ and $x \to +\infty$, while $g(x) \to +\infty$ as $x \to 0+$.  Moreover, $g'(x) = - (2x+1) \exp(1/x)/x^4$, so $g$ has a local maximum at $x=-1/2$, where the value is $4 e^{-2}$.  $g$ is increasing on $(-\infty, -1/2]$, decreasing on $[-1/2, 0)$ and on $(0,\infty)$.  Thus the $m$ values in question are $(0, 4 e^{-2})$.
Namely, if $m$ is in that interval there is one $x \in (-\infty, -1/2)$ with $g(x) = m$, one in $(-1/2, 0)$, and one in $(0,\infty)$.
Everywhere else there are at most two such $x$ values.